# Google Analytics: sudden increase in pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bots, traffic

[image]

As you can see from the picture, between 5am and 8am, there were strange increase in sessions.

I also see there are unusually huge amount of traffic from New Visitor session.
Language is (not set).  I am pretty sure this is some kind of bot.  But here is my question:

Is there anyway to track our visitor's IP address so I will know which IP is coming to spam our website shown like the picture from google analytic's point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not track user IP in google analytics, as it's against analytics terms & conditions. the other way you can do is by assigning each visitor a user-ID to track more details about each user.

thanks